# ref created by React.createRef() is null on child componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to pass a ref from parent to child component but when i access the ref inside the child `componentDidMount` it's not immediately available unlike other props i passed such as functions.

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.parentElem = React.createRef();
  }

render(){
 return(
  <div>
    <div ref={this.parentElem}>
        I can be seen by child
    </div>
    <Child parentElem={this.parentElem}/>
  </div>
 )

}

}
```

**CHILD**

```
  class Child extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
       console.log(this.props.parentElem.current) // null but looking at react dev tools its there
    }
    render(){
     return(
      <div>
     ....
      </div>
     )

    }

    }
```

versions

```
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1",
```

Comment: That's strange. [It should work](https://codesandbox.io/s/r7xyvn178q).

Comment: This sucks i even updated to 16.5 still nothing